# How do you use JNA + native libaries with JNLP web launch [on a Mac]?

Tags: java, jnlp, jna

I am attempting to launch a Java application using JNLP; the app includes a 3rd party library ([Lab Streaming Layer](https://code.google.com/p/labstreaminglayer/)) that relies on native libraries loaded with JNA.

As far as I understand, I have followed all of the appropriate steps to make this work:

1. All of the native libraries are in JAR files, separated by OS and architecture.
2. All of the native library JAR files are on the server, accessible from the codebase URL.
3. The JNLP file contains a `<resources>` element with `os` and `arch` specified with a `<nativelib>` element inside it with the correct `href` attribute.
4. The JNLP file is not malformed and launches normally.

When I go to run my application, I get a `java.lang.UnsatisifiedLinkError` that reports "Unable to load library 'liblsl32.dylib': Can't obtain InputStream for darwin/liblsl32.dylib". This happens after the program has started up, the first time it tries to make use of the library with the native lib dependency. I have corrected this **exact** error with this library with a separate, non-web-launch application by putting the dylib in the correct place. I have also tried renaming all the dylibs to be jnilibs, per this information: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jna.user/3328, but everything happens identically.

It looks like I should be able to specify `jna.library.path` in the JNLP file, but I have no idea what this would be, if it would change from launch-to-launch, or how I would find out what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

[`Native.getWebStartLibraryPath(name)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Native.html#getWebStartLibraryPath%28java.lang.String%29) should give you what you need to help JNA find the native library.

You can either construct an absolute pathname or just pass the path to [`NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(libName, path)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html#addSearchPath%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

**EDITED**

You'll also need to name your bundled OS X shared library with a `.jnilib` suffix in order for web start to recognize it as a native library.  This is a naming issue peculiar to OS X.

Comment: Native.getWebStartLibraryPath(name) is returning null, currently. The problem is that, although I know how to set it, I do not know what to set it to.

Comment: I had forgotten about the OSX shared library suffix issue with JNLP.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** the advice about using libo to get a single library to support multiple architectures (32 & 64bit) simultaneously, but the underlying issue is 1.6 related while I develop & use 1.8.

The root issue is really that OSX uses the extension `.jnilib` for libraries that it's going load, rather than `.dylib`. This means that if you're making a native jar, you should make sure that the extension for the library that you want to load is `.jnilib` rather than `.dylib`. Once you make a resource jar containing that `.jnilib` then it will be found by the JNLP classloader; otherwise JNA uses some heuristics to find it.

So, when creating your jar containing the library, you should make sure that it has a `.jnilib` extension, and is at the root of the `.jar`, so for example if we're dealing with `liblsl32.dylib`, we would do something akin to:

```
ln -fs liblsl32.dylib liblsl32.jnilib
jar cf lsl32.jar liblsl32.jnilib
```

This `lsl32.jar` is the resource that we're going to reference in our `.jnlp` file. We need to sign it; so I do this using the keystore `keystore` with the password `password` using the `myself` identity.

```
jarsigner -storepass password -keystore keystore lsl32.jar myself
```

For the resources I had to put the reference into the resource stanza of the `jnlp` file for `Mac`:

```
<resources os="Mac">
  <nativelib href="darwin.jar"/>
  <nativelib href="lsl32.jar"/>
</resources>
```

The references to `darwin.jar` is needed to load the core JNA library, and `lsl32.jar` is needed to load the `liblsl32.jnilib` library.

Instance referencing the library using:

```
Native.loadLibrary("lsl32", MyClass.class);
```

should successfully load it.

When signing the .jar files, I made sure that all of them have the relevant Codebase/Permissions attributes on-board, in a file called `file.manifest`. This file contains:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: http://localhost/demo
```

... making sure that Codebase matches your own codebase, and you update the jar using:

```
jar cfm lsl32.jar file.manifest
```

> For debug purposes, if you use `lsof` of the java process that the jnlp is running within, you can determine if it's using the JNLP loaded library or the JNA loaded library by the presence of the file in the list of loaded files, if it's using `JNLP`s mechanism, then there will be references to `liblsl32.jnilib` in the list of items, if it's using `JNA`s mechanism, then there will be no mention of the file as it's extracted to a temporary file.

---

In the 1.6 VM case, if you're not architecture compatible with the VM, and you're loading via JNA's load-mechanism, you'll get the error:

```
no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

in amongst the noise.

If you're running across multiple modes (32bit/64bit) you could merge both the 32bit and 64bit libraries into one library, and reference that, or you could just install the 64 bit library.

To put the two together, you would do something like:

```
lipo -create liblsl.jnilib liblsl32.dylib liblsl64.dylib
```

then reference `liblsl`, not `liblsl32`.

I tend to stick with the newer VM, even with all the security issues. gatekeeper prevents me from loading self-signed apps on the 1.6 VM without turning it off, which makes for an unstable testing environment.

The only webstart issues I've ever had with JNA have been caused by the enhanced security of newer JRE versions.

Comment: I'll see if this helps. I've been experimenting: if I do everything right, I get the can't obtain InputStream error; if I do something wrong (change the extension to .jnilib but leave the reference to .dylib), I get a Native library not found in resource error. I would assume the native library is corrupt, but I can load it just fine through an Eclipse launch. Starting to wonder if it is a permissions issue?

Comment: I can also use the same libraries just fine server-side on my web app.

Comment: I do also have 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the library; it is attempting to load the correct one.

Comment: jre version when you're running?

Comment: After a lot of work to stop having to deal with the latest "security", I am using 1.6.0_65.

Comment: Hmm...do I need JNA's natives in addition to LSL for web launch? I did not seem to need them for the local launch (just the jna-4.0.0.jar). I just found them while trying to sort this out.

Comment: My initial assessment was wrong; the search path is different between 1.6 and 1.8 (probably 1.7 also). When making the jar, put the .dylib into a darwin subdirectory and it should work - I'll update the answer

Comment: You *will* need to include JNA's natives as well (which is why the JNA distro includes the per-platform .jar files).

Comment: @technomage the `jna.jar` *seems* to suffice (as opposed to the `jna-min.jar` file) for finding the `libjnidispatch.jnilib` file, but the code to find the library via `Native.loadLibrary` in the 1.6 VM doesn't seem to work when the `.dylib` is in the root of the `.jar`; it only seems to work when it's in a `darwin/` subdirectory.

Comment: That makes sense.  The platform subdirectory changes weren't propagated to JNLP handling.  Feel free to file an issue on the JNA project if you feel it needs changing.

Comment: @technomage Ah, I get it now. If it's called .jnilib and in relevant jar then the native JNLP handling takes care of finding the library, otherwise JNA does some heavy lifting and finds the `.dylib` and gets that loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really call this an answer, but I did finally get this working via brute force. I modified the library I am using to request .jnilib (instead of its original .dylib), then created a native library called darwin.jar that contains the following structure:

```
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/META-INF/INTERAC.DSA
/META-INF/INTERAC.SF
/liblsl32.jnilib
/liblsl32.dylib    
/liblsl64.jnilib
/liblsl64.dylib
/darwin/liblsl32.jnilib
/darwin/liblsl32.dylib
/darwin/liblsl64.jnilib
/darwin/liblsl64.dylib
```

Unclear what about that works, but apparently this combination contains some permutation of things I had not otherwise tried. I am out of time or energy to troubleshoot further and find an exact answer. I suspect the .dylib versions of the files are not needed, since I explicitly changed the code to look for .jnilib, but they are in there for completeness sake.